# Package name doesnt match regex

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

My android studio project gives me an error "Package name doesnt match regex".

The package name is: package com.mondelicious.yuomi.Utils

Can somebody tell me what is wrong? Thank you

Comment: a guess, remove the capital U. so it becomes utils

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Naming Conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the
>   names of classes or interfaces.